# Using rand::Distribution<T> as field in struct

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, and still getting used to all the idioms in the language. I want to create an object that uses a random distribution, so I imported the `rand` and `rand_distr` crates, and am defining the object as follows:

```rust
pub struct Bandit<const K: usize> {
  levers: [f32; K],
  dist: Box<dyn Distribution<f32>>,
}
```

The `Distribution` type is defined in the `rand` crate [here](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/distributions/trait.Distribution.html).

The above code is giving me the following error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `rand_distr::Distribution` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/testbed.rs:8:15
   |
8  |     dist: Box<dyn Distribution<f32>>,
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `rand_distr::Distribution` cannot be made into an object
   |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> /Users/brendan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.8.5/src/distributions/distribution.rs:37:8
   |
37 |     fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> T;
   |        ^^^^^^ the trait cannot be made into an object because method `sample` has generic type parameters
```

My workaround for this is to define my own enum which I can map to a distribution later:

```rust
pub enum DistType {
  Normal { mean: f32, variance: f32 },
  Uniform,
}

impl DistType {
  pub fn distribution(&self) -> Box<impl Distribution<f32>> {
    match self {
        DistType::Normal { mean, variance } => /* return normal */,
        DistType::Uniform => /* return uniform */,
    }
  }
}
```

However, I don't like this solution for the reasons:

- If I can't store the distribution object, it means I have to create one whenever I need to take random samples. I suspect this will create some performance issues.
- If possible, would like to use `dyn` instead of `impl`. There may be many more of these types of distributions.
- I would prefer to avoid creating custom types like the enum I defined above because I would like to avoid unnecessary indirection.

Is there a way to persist `dyn Trait` objects that are not object safe?

- Tried dyn vs impl keywords. Reviewed the semantics of what those error and definitely do not want impl in this case
- Tried searching for ways to persist traits that are not object safe and could not find anything
- Looked for examples in the `rand_distr` crate, but all the examples create local distribution variables and use them immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you cannot have `dyn Trait` if one of your methods contains a generic parameter. However, there is  a pattern to handle this case, and it is called *type erasure*.

The idea is that we create a new trait, `ErasedDistribution`, that in its `sample()` method, instead of taking a generic parameter `R: Rng` we will take a `&mut dyn Rng`. As every `Rng` is also `&mut dyn Rng` we can implement our type for every `Distribution` out there. However, as `&mut dyn Rng` is also `Rng` we can also implement `Distribution` for `dyn ErasedDistribution`. And now we can store a `Box<dyn ErasedDistribution<f32>>`, and act as if it was `Box<dyn Distribution<f32>>` - we can store every `Distribution` inside it, and we can call `Distribution`'s methods (such as `sample_iter()`) on it or pass it to code that expects a `Distribution`.

The first step is to create our trait:

```rust
use rand::distributions::Distribution;

pub trait ErasedDistribution<T> {
    fn sample(&self, rng: &mut dyn rand::RngCore) -> T;
}
```

`Rng` is not object safe, so we cannot pass `&mut dyn Rng`. However, we got lucky: `Rng` has `RngCore` as a supertrait, and `RngCore` *is* object-safe. Furthermore, there is a blanket implementation of `Rng` for every `RngCore`, so we can just take `&mut dyn RngCore`.

If this was not the case, our erasure work would be more involved (but not impossible): we would also had to create a `ErasedRng` trait, and take `&mut dyn ErasedRng` as a parameter.

The next step is to create a blanket implementation, so every `Distribution` will also implement `ErasedDistribution`:

```rust
impl<T, D: Distribution<T> + ?Sized> ErasedDistribution<T> for D {
    fn sample(&self, rng: &mut dyn rand::RngCore) -> T {
        <Self as Distribution<T>>::sample(self, rng)
    }
}
```

The final step is to implement `Distribution` for `ErasedDistribution`. I also implemented it for `&ErasedDistribution`, because `Distribution`'s methods take `self` by move and we can't move `dyn ErasedDistribution` (we aren't covered by the blanket implementation `Distribution for &Distribution` because it is limited to `Sized` types - [I sent a PR to relax that](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/pull/1278)):

```rust
impl<T> Distribution<T> for dyn ErasedDistribution<T> {
    fn sample<R: rand::Rng + ?Sized>(&self, mut rng: &mut R) -> T {
        <dyn ErasedDistribution<T> as ErasedDistribution<T>>::sample(self, &mut rng)
    }
}

impl<T> Distribution<T> for &'_ dyn ErasedDistribution<T> {
    fn sample<R: rand::Rng + ?Sized>(&self, mut rng: &mut R) -> T {
        <dyn ErasedDistribution<T> as ErasedDistribution<T>>::sample(&**self, &mut rng)
    }
}
```

Now you can store a `Box<dyn ErasedDistribution<f32>>`. You may need to take a reference explicitly before calling `Distribution`'s methods, because Rust defaults to calling them on `dyn ErasedDistribution` instead of `&dyn ErasedDistribution`.